# How to insert enemy in the same ground level in all phones android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

I'm trying to make a game in android, using OpenGlES.

It's all working fine except this.

I have a galaxy S2 and my brother a galaxy S3.

when u run the game in my phone, the enemy steps (Y axis) exactly where I want it to be.
but on my brother's phone, the enemy is a little bit more below where i want it to be.

This image explains better:

**My phone on left and my brother's phone on right.**

[image]

The way i'm defining the enemy Y is like this:

```
   public void addSprite(float screenWidth, float screenHeight) {
        tempSprite = new NormalZombie();
        tempSprite.x = 0;
        tempSprite.y = screenHeight - 30; //IMO this is the problem
        tempSprite.startpos = screenHeight - 30;
        tempSprite.maxX = screenWidth;
        sprites.add(tempSprite);
        background = new GameBG();

    }
```

i'm pretty sure that i can't use '30' hard coded there because the difference between resolutions, but what do i need to use there to put the enemy in the same place on every phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hard coded value of `screenHeight` on you tablet and define it as constant MY_HEIGHT

```
static const int MY_HEIGHT = 800; // make the 800 your actual pixel height
```

Found 800 on wiki for [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II). Change:

```
tempSprite.y = screenHeight - 30;
tempSprite.startpos = screenHeight - 30;
```

to:

```
tempSprite.y = screenHeight - 30 * screenHeight / MY_HEIGHT;
tempSprite.startpos = screenHeight - 30 * screenHeight / MY_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: The solution was a little bit different but you gave me an ideia, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to get the screen proportion by dividing by a number that gives me the expected position.

here's how i did that:

```
    double ystart;
ystart = screenHeight - (screenHeight / 24);
tempSprite = new NormalZombie();
tempSprite.x = 0;

tempSprite.y = (float)ystart;
tempSprite.startpos = (float)ystart;
tempSprite.maxX = screenWidth;
sprites.add(tempSprite);
background = new GameBG();
```